# Why does something exist, and not nothing?

Tags: existence, nothing, objects

I have a seemingly easy looking question, but I couldn't unfortunately find an answer to it, or rather a definitive one, that leaves no doubts. The question is,
If there is a thing, what does it mean? Why does nothing not exist?

Comment: "what does it mean" you mean: the "thing"? or "there is"?

Comment: A very comprehensive article on SEP (as always :) : https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/existence/

Comment: Things exist, starting from you and me and the keyboard and... Also "meaning" exist, but you are thinking maybe about purpose, aim etc.

Comment: I asked a similar question. Why does something exist instead of nothing? This is fundamental. Meaning can connote value. How does meaning or value arise from existence? These are simple. fundamental questions. My answer is that I do not know.
I have a few ideas.

Comment: Nothing does actually exist. There's lots of it where I come from...

Answer (score 3):

I understand your question as the question “What does it mean to exist?”
Existence is such basic concept in every day life but also in philosophy, that in general one never gives a definition. At least I did not read a satisfactory definition.

The best I can do is to establish a border between the modalities “it exists”, “it is possible to exist” and “necessarily it exists”. That’s the way of modal logic to approach the question.

One always has the possibility to take “existence” as an undefined basic concept like “point, line, plane” in an axiomatized theory like Euclidean geometry. Then the meaning of the concept has to become apparent by the relation the concept has to other concepts. That's was modal logic does by introducing the concept of the one real and the many possible worlds.

Comment: In the mathematical conception of existence, a thing’s existence can pop into veridicality the moment one creates definitions. Thus once someone conceptualized the notion of prime numbers, there existed a unique example of such beasts that was also even. I guess 2 had been hanging around waiting to be granted that characterization, but until someone defines the term *ferble zammit*, it would be nonsensical to attempt to speak authoritatively about the existence of ferble zammits.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum One could also argue that definitions are only giving a name to a concept that already existed independently of whether anyone had thought of it yet.

Comment: Ah, @kutschkem, is math invented, or is it discovered? For me, I’m most comfortable on a middle ground: the axioms and definitions are invented, and the theorems are discovered. Of what use is the idea of “all the thoughts that could possibly be thought”?

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum I guess I am more comfortable with mathematicians being explorers in a strange land than the alternative of them somehow actually creating new concepts by way of invention. Your middle ground seems like a reasonable alternative view though.

Answer (score 1):

The "meaning" can be subjective based on context, ex.

- There is a ball
- There is an idea
- There is a ghost
- There is God

but in general (abstract) terms - ontologically speaking - whenever you identify (speak, write, think of) a thing (ontological being), it exists: "there is".

It is an inherent property of consciousness.

For a deeper insight in this concept, I suggest reading Parmenides, who - besides being the father of ontology - has this concept of what a thing is, in the core of his philosophy.

Answer (score 1):

> I couldn't unfortunately find an answer to it, or rather a definitive one, that leaves no doubts.

Unfortunately, you won't find such an answer. Usually philosophy is a terrible place to look for definitive answers ;-) It's just not the nature of the entire endeavor.

I highly recommend reading the SEP article I linked to earlier (I estimate a 30 min read). You've happened upon one of those Philosophical gems that are easy to state yet hard to solve :)

**To summarize**: Like many things in Philosophy, we don't have consensus as much as a variety of viewpoints and questions. The challenge is how to logically represent the sentence "x exists".

In first order quantification logic, we establish what is called a "Domain of discourse" (D) to which the quantifiers ∀x and ∃x refer, where x ∈ D. We also have predicates, such as "x is red", usually represented in capital letters and taking variables from D (e.g., R(x)).

Using this framework, the heart of the issue boils down to whether "Apples exist" should be represented as

(1) A predicate-object pair: "Apples exist(s)" = E(Apples) 
(2) General existential statement: ∃x A(x) "There exists an object x &in D such that "x is an Apple" is true.

If we look at (1) it asserts that existence is a property of individuals. This is can be problematic because the sentence "unicorns do not exist" implies that our reality includes something (unicorns) that do not exist. However, we normally conceive of reality as all the things that exist. So there is an issue of language in the naïve interpretation of Existence as a property of individuals. One solution is to admit reality includes empty names for things that do not exist. This expands reality but lets us keep "x exists" as a subject-predicate pair.

View (2) makes existence quantificational statement about a domain of discourse (reality) and that there fails to be an object to which some other non-existential predicate applies (e.g., A(x) = "x is an apple").

The SEP articles goes on in depth on this but the tension between (1) and (2) isn't settled as far as I can tell.

Comment: Re. "reality as all the things that exist", I would like to add that for Kant noumenal things can be considered real—they don't need to exist.  Collectively they are reality, (in his sense). e.g. "This conception of a sum-total of reality is the conception of a thing in itself" [CPR A572/B600](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/4280/pg4280-images.html#linknote-65). For me this is exemplified when I look before crossing a road, because in my reality something might be coming round the corner.  The reality I have to deal with is full of real possibilities only some of which become actual.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen thanks for the addition from Kant! I was summarizing the debate from philosophy of language and logic, but sounds like Kant would be firmly in the camp of a richer ontology vs restrictive one.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first distinguish between theoretical knowledge of a thing and direct experience of it.  Theoretical knowledge of say, a cup, involves its mass and the various atoms it is made of, until we reach the limit of theoretical knowledge of atoms and quarks beyond which the reality of the cup is unknown.  On the other hand, direct experience of the cup is as it appears to cognition, (as do quarks likewise appear through measurement).  Direct experience might be considered a sufficient take on reality.

As for what constitutes a thing, Aristotle formulated that things could be described as a combination of essence and predicates.  So, essence of 'cup' (its quiddity, concept), plus predicates: white, heavy, solid.

It took till the 18th century for Kant to determine that existence is not a predicate that can be attached to an essence or concept.  Existence comes about in the *judgement* that joins essence and predicate together (in a copula).  So cognition has to be involved.

[Critique of Pure Reason A598/B626](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/4280/pg4280-images.html#linknote-67), original [here](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Seite:Kant_Critik_der_reinen_Vernunft_598.png):

> ... the determination of a conception is a predicate, which adds to
> and enlarges the conception. It must not, therefore, be contained in
> the conception.
>
> Being is evidently not a real predicate, that is, a conception of
> something which is added to the conception of some other thing. It is
> merely the positing of a thing, or of certain determinations in it.
> Logically, it is merely the copula of a judgement.

Note this explanation is for the type of existence of a **thing**.  The living, experiencing existence that makes the judgement is of a higher order.